# How to Join 3 Tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join

I am creating a view for my Database , I am joing 3 tables, Users,personal_info and contact_info, if you notice I have a lot of column names in my Select statement , since i don't want to include primary keys but it seems I have an error here, take a look

```
CREATE VIEW `payroll`.`new_view` AS
Select employee_id,employee_password,First_Name,Middle_Initial,
Last_Name,Date_Of_Birth,Beneficiaries,Home_Number,Address,Mobile_Number,Email_Address
From USER
LEFT JOIN personal_info on idUser = idPersonal_Info,
FULL JOIN contact_info on idUser = idContact_Info
```

The error is

```
ERROR 1146: Table 'payroll.full' doesn't exist

SQL Statement:

CREATE  OR REPLACE VIEW `payroll`.`new_view` AS

Select employee_id,employee_password,First_Name,Middle_Initial,

Last_Name,Date_Of_Birth,Beneficiaries,Home_Number,Address,Mobile_Number,Email_Address

From USER

LEFT JOIN personal_info on idUser = idPersonal_Info,

FULL JOIN contact_info on idUser = idContact_Info
```

Comment: can u add the structure of each table? because its hard to find out which columns belong to which tables.

Comment: There is no `FULL JOIN` in MySQL. You have to emulate it with a `UNION` of a `LEFT` and a `RIGHT` join.

Comment: You also have a comma that doesn't make sense, after: `LEFT JOIN personal_info on idUser = idPersonal_Info,`

Answer (score 0):

Error on:

**LEFT JOIN personal_info on idUser = idPersonal_Info**

you need to specify which column on which table equals which one on the other table, like

```
  SELECT a,b,c from table1 
  LEFT JOIN table2
   on table1.a= table2.columnY
```

in your case:

```
on USER.idUser =  Personal_Info.idPersonalInfo
```

and the same for the 3rd Join

Another thing is the Comma at the end of the line:

LEFT JOIN personal_info on idUser = idPersonal_Info **,**

it doesnt belong there.

Comment: If there are no conflicts, there is no need for that. But it's good advice, for clarity and maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

quote it with backtics:  `payroll.new_view`

```
CREATE VIEW `payroll.new_view`
```